# How to check relation data of a collection before sending it to view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

I have a Controller method like this:

```
public function awaiting()
    {
        $producers = Producer::where('producer_process',4)->get();
        $producers_list = [];
        foreach($producers as $producer){
            if($producer->brand->brand_rejected == 0){
                array_push($producers_list, $producer);
            }
        }

        return view('admin.brands.awaiting', compact('producers_list'));
    }
```

So basically there's **One To One** relationship between `Producer` model & `Brand` model.

In order to get the collection of `brands` table records that has `producer_process` of **4** and ALSO the `brand_rejected` field of related `brands` table record must be set to **0**, I added an `array_push` and check the condition.

Now this works fine and properly shows the correct data but I wanted to know, what is the shorthand method of doing this with Eloquent relationships?

I mean is there any concise and useful method written in Eloquent relationships that can do this without using `array_push` or another `foreach` loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `whereHas` to constrain the result set based on the existence of a relationship. Here we are saying we only want producers that have the field 'produce_process' set to 4 and have a brand with a field of 'brand_rejected' set to 0:

```
$producers = Producer::where('producer_process', 4)
    ->whereHas('brand', function ($q) { $q->where('brand_rejected', 0); })
    ->get();
```

If you want these producers to have their brand relationship loaded to use you should eager load that. Before the `get` call you can tell it to load the relationship:

```
$producers = Producer::where(...)->whereHas(...)->with('brand')->get();
```

[Laravel 5.8 Docs - Eloquent - Relationships - Querying Relationship Existence](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) `whereHas`

[Laravel 5.8 Docs - Eloquent - Relationships - Eager Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) `with`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
public function awaiting()
{
    $producers = Producer::where('producer_process',4)
      ->with('brand', function($q) {
          $q->where('brand_rejected', 0);
    })->get();

    // dd($producers);
    dd($producers->pluck(brand));
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can use the method `with()` also with the `where()` clause to can apply some conditions to the relationship

Example

```
$yourQuery->with('brand', function($query){
  $query->where('brand_rejected', 0);
});
```

check this for more info

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads

I hope it's helpful